# el boton no agrega informacion al div

Tags: array, botón, div

lo que yo quiero intentar hacer es agregar los valores del input al array cajita y que cuando yo toque el boton de agregar mediante la función botón, estos mismos valores se visualicen en el div

```js
var cajita = [];

var listado = document.getElementById('listado');
var txtTareas = document.getElementById(txtTareas)
var tareas = txtTareas.value



function boton(){
    
    cajita.push(tareas.value);
    listado.innerHTML= cajita;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body><form action="">
    <label> Tareas: </label><input type="text" id="txtTarea" placeholder="ingrese su tarea"/>
    <button id="btnAgregar" onclick="boton()">Agregar</button>
    </form>
<div id="listado">

</div>
    <script src="matrices y arrays.js"></script>
    <script src="listado.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sólo te faltaban pequeños detalles. Como el id "txtTarea" no lo estas escribiendo bien en el js. Luego cuando haces el push al array **cajita** haces de nuevo tareas.value pero en la variable de arriba "tareas" ya tienes el valor guardado correctamente. De resto, todo esta correcto. Te escribo el código como lo modifique:

```
<form name="form" id="tarea_frm" action="#">
    <label> Tareas: </label>
    <input type="text" id="txtTarea" name="tarea" placeholder="ingrese su tarea"/>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="btnAgregar" value="Agregar" onclick="boton();" />
    </form>
<div id="listado"></div>
```

```
function boton(){
  var cajita = [];
  var listado = document.getElementById("listado");
  var txtTareas = document.getElementById("txtTarea");
  var tareas = txtTareas.value
  cajita.push(tareas);
  listado.innerHTML= cajita;
}
```

Un saludo

Comment: sos un groso, tengo una duda, porque agregaste el boton como un input ?

Comment: Le añadí input porque es como suelo hacerlo yo pero se puede hacer de las dos formas, al final es lo mismo. No te sabría decir una diferencia clara entre ambas formas @alejandrodelgado

Comment: @alejandrodelgado Mira he encontrado la diferencia por si te sirve para un futuro. **input:** Permite crear un simple botón que solo puede incluir texto en su atributo value y es lo que se muestra en el botón.
**button:** Permite crear un botón pero con html dentro, o sea puedes incluir iconos, imágenes, etc. Pd: pensaba que sos un groso era un insulto por eso conteste antes mas seca jajaj perdona.

Comment: jajajjaja me parecio que me habias contestado seca, aca en argentina eso significa algo bueno, gracias por tomarte la molestia de explicarme las diferencias. pero ahora me sale otra problematica, al apretar el boton la informacion que escriba en el imput aparece muy rapidamente y se borra del div, no se porque se limpian

Comment: @alejandrodelgado jajajja sorry, soy de España, no sabia el significado xD. Hmm probando se me borra la información si lo ponto tipo button como lo tenías. Si lo pongo input aparentemente va bien. ¿Cómo lo estas probando?

Comment: lo estaba probando como button, lo probé como vos lo hiciste y funciona bien. Entonces llegue a la conclusión de que a mi button le faltaba el type ='submit' ya que tiene que enviar los valores del array al div jajajaj. muchas gracias por la ayuda, sos una grosa jajaj

Comment: @alejandrodelgado jajaja de nada. Me alegra haberte ayudado :)